# Can we grant permissions to perform SHOW LOCKS IN ACCOUNT to a role in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can we grant permissions to perform `SHOW LOCKS IN ACCOUNT` to a role in Snowflake

Or only Admins can do that?

Answer (score 1):

you need to be accountadmin to see those:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-locks.html#parameters